# Why can't I use Array.prototype.join.call as a callback of a Promise?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run this code:

```js
Promise.resolve([1, 2]).then(Array.prototype.join.call).then(console.log);
```

Which is (according to me) an equivalent of this:

```js
Promise.resolve([1, 2]).then(x => x.join()).then(x => console.log(x));
```

It actually fails with error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined is not a function

Can someone explain? I also tried `Array.prototype.join.apply`, but the result is the same.

Comment: You "break" the relationship between the `.join` method and `.call` when you pass the reference to `.then()`; it's as if you passed `Function.prototype.call` to `.then()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method is not a function. It needs a `this` reference.

> *"The **`call()`** method calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided individually."*

You will need to pass the response directly to it, or just call:

> ```js
> response.join()
> ```

### Working example

```js
Promise.resolve([1, 2])
  .then(response => Array.prototype.join.call(response))
  .then(console.log)
```

---

### Alternatively...

You can create a binder function.

```js
const bindMethod = (method, scope) => ((ref) =>
    (value) =>
      ref.call.bind(ref)(value))(scope === undefined
        ? method
        : scope.prototype[method])

Promise.resolve([1, 2])
  .then(bindMethod(Array.prototype.join))
  .then(console.log)
  
Promise.resolve([1, 2])
  .then(bindMethod('join', Array))
  .then(console.log)
```

Comment: but ... it definitely *is* a function

Comment: @Pointy it's a method that takes an option `thisArg` If you did not supply it, it will assume otherwise.

Comment: There's no meaningful difference between the terms "method" and "function" in JavaScript.

Comment: I think I see what you mean however

Comment: @Pointy There most definitely is a difference. Methods take a receiving object.

Comment: The OP could pass `Array.prototype.join.call.bind(Array.prototype.join)` though that would be pretty ridiculous

Comment: Yeah I got it, it's because `call` needs an internal `this` and it should be `Array.prototype.join`

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for the tip, I created a binder.

Comment: @GuerricP I added an alternative example.