# getting an error when passing some parameters

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner so it this may not be a very smart question ..
If I have this function

```
function repeat (n,action) {
      for(i=0;i<n;i++){
          action(i) 
      }
 }
```

if I implement it in this way `repeat (3,console.log)` it works.
why do I get an error if I pass it this parameters:

```
let arr = [0]; 
repeat(3,arr.push);
```

since `action(i)` will be replaced -as I think-  with `arr.push(i)`

Answer (score 5):

The `Array.prototype.push` method is not a function and cannot be used as a callback, unless it is binded. It expects a `this` to be passed in as the scope of the call.

See: [*Why can't I use Array.prototype.join.call as a callback of a Promise?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62839609/1762224)

You have two options:

- `repeat(3, arr.push.bind(arr));` (binded-method callback)
- `repeat(3, v => arr.push(v));` (lambda-style callback)

```js
function repeat(n, action) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    action(i)
  }
}

repeat(3, console.log);

console.log

let arr = [0];
repeat(3, arr.push.bind(arr));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `repeat(3,arr.push.bind(arr));` - binding it like that works